# Return a deferred object as a fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

It doesn't seem like I can return a deferred object if it failed. I have a pretty nested ajax request that goes into a queue so I need a way to return the request as a deferred object. Everything is great if the request is successful, but I am stuck on getting failures to propagate.

https://jsfiddle.net/3wtady9r/

```
function doAjax(file) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var fakeFile = file;
    var data = null;

    ajax();

    function ajax() {
        return $.get(fakeFile)
            .done(function(data) {
                data = data;
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                defer.fail();
            })
    }
    return defer.promise(data);
}

var thisWillWork = '';

doAjax(thisWillWork)
    .done(function() {
        console.log('done')
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.error('fail')
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log('always')
    })

var thisWontWork = 'fakeFile.html'
doAjax(thisWontWork)
    .done(function() {
        console.log('done')
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.error('fail')
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log('always')
    })
```

When I do doAjax(thisWontWork) I am expecting to get the console error and also .always, but neither fire.

Comment: Some strange stuff. You're calling `ajax()` and ignoring the return value. You have `data = data;`, but that only assigns to the parameter, not the `var data = null`, so the `defer.promise(data)` is still passing `null`

Comment: This looks like a horribly failed attempt to implement the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) to me. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of different issues there.

1. [`fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) is a method for hooking up handlers to get called if the promise is rejected. To *reject* it, use [`reject`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/).
2. You don't want to pass `data` into `defer.promise` at the end.
3. You don't want or need a `data` *variable* at all, just the argument you receive in `success`.
4. Since you never use the value you return from your own `ajax` function, there's no need to return it.
5. jQuery's `ajax` *already* returns a promise that does what your promise does, so your promise can just be removed entirely. This happens often enough [there's an antipattern named for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). *Every time* you think you need to create a promise, stop yourself and think: Do I already have one? Sure, sometimes the answer is no, but often it's yes. :-)

As of point #5, we end up with:

```
function doAjax(file) {
    var fakeFile = file;

    return $.get(fakeFile);
}
```

...which means, of course, that you don't need `doAjax` *at all*. Just call `$.get`.

But if for some reason you haven't shared you need your own promise, then just points 1-4:

```
function doAjax(file) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var fakeFile = file;

    ajax();

    function ajax() {
        $.get(fakeFile)
            .done(function(data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                defer.reject();
            });
    }
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: This is a really simplified version of what I have going on. This function is actually passed into a queue so it needs to be returned like this. Thank you for the fixes.

Comment: @BarryBones41: Glad that helped. At the end of the day, it doesn't matter if this is in a queue or something, if it returns a promise that gets fulfilled with `data` or rejected based on the result of the `$.get`, then you can return the promise from `$.get`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `defer.reject();` not `defer.fail();`

Also you can add data in the reject like you did in defer.resolve().